# AWS Tookit not able to connect to AWS account via shared credentials in VSCode

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed the AWS Toolkit in VSCode and trying to connect to my AWS account. It is throwing socket closed error.

Apparently, it works just fine in intelliJ

Check the below logs:
Which socket is closed for this action?

Credentials File

```
[saml]
aws_access_key_id        = xxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key    = xxxxxxx
```

Logs

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [INFO]: autoconnect: trying "profile:saml"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [ERROR]: Error: Socket is closed
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:785:8)
    at Socket._write (node:net:807:8)
    at doWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:408:12)
    at clearBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:569:7)
    at Socket.Writable.uncork (node:internal/streams/writable:348:7)
    at ClientRequest._flushOutput (node:_http_outgoing:969:10)
    at ClientRequest._flush (node:_http_outgoing:938:22)
    at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:818:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'xxxxx',
  hostname: 'xxxxx',
  retryable: true,
  time: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  statusCode: 407
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy was not configured inside VsCode that lead to socket closed error. I added proxy details and it connected successfully.
File --> Preferences -> Settings --> Applications --> Proxy.